# How to solve subprocess.run() execution error?

Tags: python, subprocess

this is my code:

```
import subprocess

completed = subprocess.run(['ls', '-1'])
print('returncode:', completed.returncode)
```

this is the error i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getDataFromOpenImages_snowman.py", line 3, in <module>
    completed = subprocess.run(['ls', '-1'])
  File "C:\Users\pavan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\pavan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\pavan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Question: what is the problem with my code?

Comment: `ls` is not a Windows command. It's a built-in `bash` command. Often, a binary command (e.g. `/usr/bin/ls` on my cygwin) can be found as well. `_winapi.CreateProcess` tells me you are on Windows. You may try `dir` instead of `ls`, or you provide an `ls` command which can be called. (Instead of `cygwin`, [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) could be used as well.)

Comment: thank you. i understood where i did wrong.